# numpy in simple nearest centroid classifier

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

**Question:** How can the following code be improved in terms of (1) efficiency, (2) memory, and (3) style / simplicity?

```
train_means = np.mean(train_data.reshape(784, 10, 1000), axis=2)
train_classes, test_classes = (np.argmin(np.sum(np.square(data[:,:,np.newaxis] - train_means[:,np.newaxis,:]), axis=0), axis=1) for data in (train_data, test_data))
train_acc, test_acc = (np.mean(np.equal(classes, np.repeat(np.arange(10), classes.size // 10))) for classes in (train_classes, test_classes))
```

Here is the specification of the variables and problem:

```
# train_data: shape of (784, 10000)
#  test_data: shape of (784, 1000)
#
# In both cases, each column is a vectorization of a 28 x 28 image of a handwritten digit
# (0-9) where the correct classification is 0 for the first tenth of the columns, 1 for
# the second tenth, and so on. The goal is to write a nearest centroid classifier and
# output its accuracy on each data set.
```

For instance, one concern I have is that in the subtraction `data[:,:,np.newaxis] - train_means[:,np.newaxis,:]`, a `(784, 10000, 10)` array is created, which is more memory than I need to use. Could I avoid allocating this much memory while not sacrificing any efficiency (and ideally any simplicity of code)?

Another concern is the comprehension I use to apply the procedures to both the training data and testing data. Would that be encouraged or considered convoluted (or maybe this is just irrelevant personal preference)?

**Context:** This is my attempt to write a numpy-optimized version of a nearest centroid classifier to classify some images from the MNIST data set of handwritten digits. I am somewhat new to numpy and was surprised by how succinctly this code could be written with the help of broadcasting and vectorized operations, but was wondering if I was still missing some possibly important improvements.

Comment: This question seems better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OferSadan Ah I didn't know that existed. I'll likely move it there in a bit then.